# Getting variable passed in URL with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to get the ID which was passed in the URL but it seems something goes wrong!

This is my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/poste/{idp}',array('before' => 'members_auth',function($id){
//dd($id);

$post =Posts::where('idp','=',$id) -> get();

$titre=$post->titre;

$desc=$post->description;

return View::make('showPost',array('title'=>$titre,'description'=>$desc));
}));
```

And this is my View

```
<a href="/poste/{{$userpost->idp}}">
```

The error was `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$titre`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite common issue when you start with Eloquent ORM. Basically `get()` method always returns Collection of objects, even if there is only one found. Sure enough Collection object has no `titre` property. If `idp` is primary key for your Post model, you should use `find()` or `findOrFail()` method instead.

```
$post = Posts::find($id);
```

As Laravel documentation states:

> Note: Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key
>   column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this
>   convention. Likewise, you may define a connection property to override
>   the name of the database connection that should be used when utilizing
>   the model.

You are free to override your primary key.

```
class Posts extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idp';
}
```

Comment: Yes idp is a primary key , but when i tried with  
$post = Posts::find($id);
return View::make('showPost')->with('idpost',$post->idp);
it shows this error :
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `posts` where `id` = 25